# Android: URL is not opening PlayStore App while using Internet Browser

Tags: android, url, redirect, browser, user-agent

I have an interesting issue with android and the PlayStore.

When the user enters my website on the mobile browser I will re-direct them to the PlayStore to download my application with referrer ID's to track the install.

This works great in Chrome, however it's not currently working with Internet Browser.

**Example:**
User opens up my http://example.com url using Internet Browser

This in turn redirects them to:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.mobile&referrer=pid%3D2111%26spid%3D%257Bpublisher_sub1%257D%26us_tid%3D-1737673180

**The problem:**
The internet browser continues opening up the PlayStore inside the browser. 

**Expected:**
Prompt user to open the link using Chrome/Internet Browser/PlayStore app.

I've cleared the Internet Browser default settings. I'm missing something simple I believe.

Thanks!

Comment: Was looking into market://, but latest google docs suggest to use the http://play.google.com and market is just for android apps themselves.